# Confused about Serge Lang's proof of hermitian operator has real eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra

On Serge Lang's linear algebra page 225:

Theorem 5.1: Let $A:V\to V$ be a hermitian operator. Then every eigenvalue of $A$ is real.

Proof: Let $v$ be an eigenvector with an eigenvalue $\lambda$. By Theorem 2.4 of Chapter VII we know that $<Av,v>$ is real. Since $Av=\lambda v$, we find $<Av,v>=\lambda <v,v>$. But $<v,v>$ is real $>0$ by assumption. Hence $\lambda$ is real, thus proving the theorem.

Theorem 2.4 Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the complex numbers. Let $A$ be an operator such that $<Av,v>=0$ for all $v\in V$. Then $A =o$.

I don't understand why Theorem 2.4 can prove that $<Av,v>$ is real, and what assumption makes $<v,v>$ real.

(There're some proofs of the title much easier to understand, for example https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Hermitian_Matrix_has_Real_Eigenvalues, but I just can't understand the specific proof method which Lang use.)

Comment: Im pretty sure it's a typo and he meant theorem 2.5

Comment: @TomAriel, thanks with theorem 2.5, $<Av, v>$ is real makes sense. But why $<v, v>$ is real? I think by definition it only need to be $>0$?

Comment: $x>0$ implies x is real.

Comment: @TomAriel It's a silly question, I real don't understand why $x>0$ implies $x$ is real.

Comment: The silly argument: if $x$ has nonzero imaginary part, the expression $x>0$ is nonsense - the complex numbers aren't ordered. The real argument: usually $\langle v | v \rangle $ is real for all v" is left out since it is sort of implied in the expression $\langle v | v \rangle \geq 0$, given the aforementioned silly argument.

Comment: @TomAriel Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $v \neq 0$ is an eigenvector, then $||v||^{2} = \langle v | v \rangle >0$ (from the definition of an inner product), and $\lambda \langle v | v\rangle = \langle \lambda v | v\rangle =  \langle Av | v \rangle = \langle v | Av \rangle = \langle v | \lambda v\rangle = \lambda ^{*} \langle v | v \rangle  $, and since $\langle v | v\rangle \neq 0 $ we get $\lambda = \lambda^{*}$ so $\lambda$ is real.